# SQLite EF6 select qeury bad data

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework, запрос, linq

Есть проект на C#. Использую EF6 совместно с System.Data.SQLite, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, System.Data.SQLite.LINQ.

Domain:

Company.cs:

```
[Table("CompanyList")]
public class Company()
{
    [Key]
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Product> Products {get;set;}
}
```

Product.cs:

```
[Table("ProductList")]
public class Product()
{
    [Key]
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<string> Params {get;set;}
}
```

В Application нужно получить список компаний, в имени или параметрах продуктов которых содержится поисковая строка (в 95% случаев строка будет только из русских символов, без цифр).

Application.cs

```
public List<Company> SearchBy(string searchString)
{
    AppContext.CompanyList.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(searchString) || 
                                   c.Products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(searchString)).Count() > 0 ||
                                   c.Products.Where(p => p.Params.Where(param => param.Contains(searchString)).Count() > 0).Count() > 0);
}
```

Программа может работать как с MSSQL, так и с SQLite.
При выполнении данного запроса к MSSQL все работает без проблем, а при выполнении запроса к SQLite возвращает верные компании + в которых нет данных по поисковой строке.

Подскажите в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Замените для начала все `.Where(...).Count() > 0` на `.Any(...)`, а то невозможно же читать такое, слишком много лишних букв в запросах. Да и работает оно не оптимально. А по сути - точно у вас где-нибудь в `CompanyList.Products.Params` нет искомой строки, вы уверены? Да и `Product.Name` у вас тоже проверяется. Кстати, а что проверяет `param.Contains`, я вообще что-то не пойму, какое поле?

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в использовании кирилицы. Проведите тест с поиском по латинице. Попробуй [эту строку подключения](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5893808/3129992) как вариант. Поправь заголовок вопроса...

Comment: какой запрос сформировался в логах?

Comment: По умолчанию SQLite чувствителен к регистру (case-sensitive), а Sql Server - не чувствителен (case-insensitive). Возможно, дело в этом.

Comment: Хотя нет, дело явно в кодировке или collation. Вот документация для EF Core: [Collations and Case Sensitivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/collations-and-case-sensitivity). В EF6 всё несколько сложнее. Нужно или в строке соединения charset указать. Или же вот изучайте: [Collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/collation)